# Are there other LSM (Linux Security Modules) in addition to SELinux and AppArmor?

Tags: selinux, apparmor, lsm

In researching this U&L Q&A titled: [permission denied for ptrace under GDB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106912/permission-denied-for-ptrace-under-gdb), the question came up, "Is there other software similar to SELinux & AppArmor?".

User [@IwillnotexistIdonotexist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106951/7453) mentioned 2 that I'd never heard of: Smack & Yama. He found them by searching through the Linux source code. So now we're up to 4.

- SELinux
- AppArmor
- Smack
- Yama

Are there others?

Comment: [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In searching for Linux Security Modules, I came across the wikipedia page, titled: [Linux Security Modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules).

These are the following LSM's listed there:

- [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux)
- [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor)
- [Smack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smack_%28Linux_security_module%29)
- [TOMOYO Linux](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/)
- [YAMA LSM](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2d514487faf188938a4ee4fb3464eeecfbdcf8eb)
- [Linux Intrusion Detection System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Intrusion_Detection_System)
- [FireFlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=FireFlier&action=edit&redlink=1)
- [CIPSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CIPSO&action=edit&redlink=1)
- [Multi ADM](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Multi_ADM&action=edit&redlink=1)

Of the modules listed, the first 4, SELinux, AppArmor, Smack, and TOMOYO Linux are the only ones accepted into the official Linux Kernel, since version 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [grsecurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grsecurity). grsecurity isn't a LSM system per se, rather, it's a set of patches to the Linux kernel, all focused on security. Looking at the Wikipedia page, the project appears inactive (last stable release only works on kernel source trees up to kernel 3.2.50, and the latest preview release only works up on kernel source trees up to kernel 3.4.4).